# Google cloud machine shutdown automaticaaly and and ip address change

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

This is regarding VM machine bitnami-wordpress-77fb and we have hosted sanver.com on this machine.

The sanver.com was not resolving, we checked and found that the machine was shutdown and ip address changed.

The previous ip address of VM machine was 130.211.77.24 and now it has changed to 104.155.55.243.

Comment: You should use Static IP (you will be billed for it) if you don't want the IP to change on the instance restart.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a technical support request for Google services rather than a question.

Answer (score 2):

By default, an ephemeral external IP address is assigned to Google Compute Engine instances for the lifetime of the instance. Instance reboot/shutdown would cause a new ephemeral IP address to be assigned to the instance.

See more information here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#ephemeraladdress